# Netlify deployed project - Page not found

Tags: netlify

i have deployed a Vue app using Vite to Netlify. I am using Vue router to changed pages in the project and all of the different pages work apart from the profile page which i get a page not found error.[image]

I don't really know how to fix this issue as all other pages work apart from this one. Does anyone have any advice on how I could solve this issue? Thanks

(PS: all the pages work in local host)

Answer (score 1):

In my case,`window.location.reload()` was causing error. After I removed it, it worked